# Labeling diagonal arrows with the diagrams package

Tags: diagrams

As far as I can tell, the following code

```
\usepackage[balance,small]{diagrams}

...

\begin{diagram}
&& X && \\
& \ldTo^\Phi & & \rdTo^\Psi &\\
Y &&&& Z
\end{diagram}
```

should produce a diagram with diagonal arrows and labels which are horizontal (i.e. not slanted with the arrows), at least that's what happens in Milne's documentation (http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mdiagrams.pdf). However my labels (Phi and Psi) are slanted along the arrow.

How do I make it so the labels are horizontal?

Comment: The space above is reserved for questions and the space below is intended to be where people look for answers. It would be nice if you edited the above to be a question, and provided a self answer below.  That way this could be useful to others who encounter a similar problem.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if that was appropriate. Apparently I must wait till tomorrow to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the option [nohug] will make it so that labels do not slant with the arrow. The top line should be:

```
\usepackage[balance,small,nohug]{diagrams}
```